# Group by a column that has repeating data in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Table cart
[image: cart]

**Table cart_addons**

[image: cart_addons]

**Currently getting:**

```
[134]
   -[52]
[135]
   -[49]
```

**Expected output as Array:**

```
[134]
  -[52]
[135]
  -[49]
  -[50]
  -[51]
```

Which means getting only a single row based on each `cart_id`

**Model**

```
function get_total_sum_of_addons_by_cartid($id)
    {
       
        $this->db->query("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));"); //prevent error of non aggregate columns
        $this->db->select('a.aid');
        $this->db->from('cart_addons AS a, cart as c');
        $this->db->where('a.cart_id', $id);
        $this->db->group_by('a.cart_id');
        $query = $this->db->get('cart_addons');    
        $result_array = $query->result_array();
         
        return $result_array;
        
    }
```

Cannot figure it out why I cannot get the excepted output, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The results are as expected the way you now use group by. Group by is only necessary if you want to use sum or any other aggregate function. Use a regular JOIN between the tables to get the results you want.

Comment: You could also try to group by both columns to see if you get closer to your expected results: `$this->db->group_by(array("a.cart_id", "a.aid"));`

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just applied an alternate approach and now I'm getting my expected results.

```
function get_total_sum_of_addons_by_cartid($id)
{
   
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('cart_addons')
             ->where('`cart_id` in', '(select `id` from `cart` where `id` = '.$id.')', false)
             ->get(); 
    $result_array = $query->result_array();
     
    return $result_array;
    
}
```

The `$result_array` now returning as following output if `cart_id = 135`:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [cart_id] => 135
            [aid] => 49
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [cart_id] => 135
            [aid] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [cart_id] => 135
            [aid] => 51
        )

)
```